# I want my button to increase my products but I am getting two problems

Tags: reactjs

The first problem is when I use:

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(4);
```

and put it in:

```
  products.slice(0, visible)
```

It is showing me all the products rather than 4. This issue doesn't occur when I use it like this:

```
products.slice(0, 4)
```

The second problem is that I want my button "Load More" to increase value of Visible but it is not working.
Here is the complete code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './ForYou.css'
import ForYouItem from './ForYouItem'


export default function ForYou(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(4);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setProducts(data))
    }, [])
    const showMoreItems = () => {
        setVisible((prevValue) => prevValue + 4) 
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="ForYou-container">
                <div className="heading">
                    <a href="#" className='Big-text'> {props.Bigheading}</a>
                </div>
                <div className="row ">
                {products.slice(0, visible).map((product) => {                   
                    return(                                      
                        <div className="col-md-3 my-2 Products">
                    <ForYouItem Title={product.title.slice(0,50)} Price={product.price} Imageurl = {product.image}/>
                    </div>
                
                
                )
                
                }
                
                )}
                <button className='Load-btn' onClick={showMoreItems}>Load More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Code for child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './ForYouItem.css'
export default function ForYouItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <a href="#">
                    <div class="card" >
                        <img src={props.Imageurl} class="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"> {props.Title}... </h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Rs.{props.Price}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex justify-content-center btn btn-danger">Buy Now!</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your Code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and make a few modifications since there was no code for the child component so I can make it work. However I did not find any errors, check this code to see if you get any ideas on how to implement the increasing  of the items and check the **ForYouItems** component as there might be the issue since it renders ok with less data.

```
  import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

  const ForYouItem = ({Title})=>{
    return <>
      <div>{Title}</div>
    </>
  }

  export default function ForYou(props)  {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(4);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setProducts(data))
    }, [])
    const showMoreItems = () => {      
      setVisible((prevValue) => prevValue + 4) 
    }
    return (
        <div>          
            <div className="ForYou-container">                
                <div className="heading">
                  <a href="#" className='Big-text'>props.Bigheading</a>
                </div>
                <div className="row ">
                {products.slice(0, visible).map((product) => {                   
                  return(
                    <div className="col-md-3 my-2 Products">
                      <ForYouItem Title={product.title.slice(0,50)} />
                    </div>
                  )
                }                
                )}
                {
                  visible <= products.length-1 && 
                    <button className='Load-btn' onClick={showMoreItems}>Load More</button>
                }                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```